# Expanding exisitng VBA code with CountIf conditions

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm trying to figure out how to expand the code below with the following countif conditions:

- If a row in **Workbbook 1(wbSource)**  has the values in **Column H =
  "01.January" and Column AD = < 50** then count and enter the result in
  **cell B8 in Sheet 2 of Workbook 2(ThisWorkbook**) after the whole
  wbSource is checked.
- If a row in **wbSource** has the values **Column H = "01.January" and
  Column AD = > 50 and < 100** then count and enter the result in **cell B9 in Sheet 2 of ThisWorkbook** after the whole wbSource  is checked.
- If a row in **wbSource** has the values **Column H = "01.January" and Column AD = > 100** then count and enter the result in **cell B10 in Sheet 2 of ThisWorkbook** after the whole wbSource is checked.

**This should be repeated for every month.**

The entire concept is based around an user form with a file explorer function, where the user can select an excel file and evaluate it automatically based on the avarage_calc and countif conditions by clicking on a command button. Thats why I would need it as VBA.

Any idea how to add the countif function based on the conditions above, as addition to my existing code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages
     Const YEAR = 2019

    ' open source workbook
    Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

    ' scan down source workbook calc average
    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
    Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow

        If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then

            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   ' col H
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) ' Col AD
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '

        End If
    Next

    ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False

    ' update Table 2 with averages
    With ws.Range("A3")
    For iMth = 1 To 12
        .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & YEAR
        If count(iMth) > 0 Then
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End If
    Next
    End With


    Dim msg As String
    msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Table 2 updated"

End Sub
```

**Wb result sheet2**
[image]

**wb.Source sheet1**
[image]

Comment: I wonder, if (this and that), then what range is to count ? Or do you mean (1) count column AD if column H is certain value.... then (2) if the count result (of column AD) is =< 50 then put it in Sheet2 cell B8 ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I want the code to count row x if cells of row x in column AD & H are fulfilling the conditions. This is basically all I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are looking for, forgive me if I've missed the point completely. You should be able to throw this at the bottom of your existing code. A few notes:

- Since I'm assuming you don't want each month's values to overwrite the previous month's, I made January go in column B, February in C, etc. (it's the `1+x` portion if you want to change it).
- EDIT: The loop 1 to 12 paired with the `m =` function will loop through the date ranges you're looking for.
- I also changed the formulas for the second and third functions so that you don't have overlap (as 1 had <= 50 and 2 had >= 50, so anything equaling 50 would have shown up in both).

  ```
  Dim x as Long
  Dim m as Date

  For x = 1 To 12

      m = CDate(x & "/1/2019")

      ws.Cells(8, 1 + x) = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m, _
          wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 50)

      ws.Cells(9, 1 + x) = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m, _
          wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 50, wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 100)

      ws.Cells(10, 1 + x) = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m, _
          wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 100)

  Next x
  ```

Comment: thanks @barvobot! This looks very promising.But the problem is that the code results in  "0" for every month. Is it maybe because of the month format? The month format in the source sheet is like this:  "01.02.2019" .

Comment: one more thing: only the rows with the first of the month should be considered. Meaning: 01.01, 01.02, 01.03 etc. I'm not sure if your code coveres this conditions.

Comment: Gotcha. I changed my answer to something that should work better. I made the `CountIfs` formulas accept a wildcard for year but if you just wanted a specific year I put in a commented out version of `m = ` that specifies the year.

Comment: there is a sytax error - all of the ws.Cells lines are highlited red. Do you maybe know why? thanks!

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the " m & * " part? The error message is pointing at the * with "expected expression".

Comment: ok, I figured out that the quotes were missing - "*". But still, the code results in zeros... As seen in the screenshot above.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot the "'s, whoops! Can you post a screenshot of your source data (i.e. wsSource)? Is the data in column H formatted as text, date, etc.? Using `m & "*"` assumes Text or General format

Comment: sure :) I've uploaded a screenshot of some row examples of the source sheet. The dates in column 8 are true dates.

Comment: Ok, that would do it! :) I changed the `m` variable to the Date variable type and tweaked the `m = ` formula to produce a true date value instead of a string. This should work regardless of the date format on the wsSource page as well.

Comment: Still getting only zeros as result...dont understand why? Your code looks good, but the counting still fails? is it maybe because the values in column 30 are decimals? Values like 104.5, 35.5, 89.2 etc. Sorry if my screenshot example wasn't sufficient.

Comment: Decimals should work fine with those functions as written, assuming the values are in a numeric format (i.e. not Text). Can you do a regular cell formula to get the value, e.g. put `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!H:H,DATE(2019,1,1),Sheet1!AD:AD,"<="&50)` in cell B8 of 'Table 2' sheet?